# Tag synonym request for "descriptor" and "descriptors"

Tags: support, status-completed, stack-overflow, tags, retag-request

[descriptor](/questions/tagged/descriptor) 51 questions
[descriptors](/questions/tagged/descriptors) 37 questions

Just a singular and plural, it shouldn't be controversial. There are enough questions, but not enough people have 5 votes for the community to do this. I don't have a strong opinion on which way the synonym should go.

Comment: The notification works; it doesn't come up as autocomplete because an editor is probably automatically notified in the same way the OP is notified (I don't remember where I read it). Between [meta-tag:tag-synonym] and [meta-tag:stackoverflow] I thought it was more appropriate the latter one, and because the 5-tag limit, I had to choose between the two tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tagged `status-completed` by Robert Harvey. Answering so this doesn't sit with no accepted answer.